# File Reading Temperature Converter

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am currently working on a project which requires me to read Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures from a file and convert them to the opposite. After the conversion I have to output the originally temp. and type then the converted temp and type with this format:

[image]

The formatting for the file that I'm reading from looks like this.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For a start, checkout the [FileReader API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) in order for you to embed a form that will enable the user to upload the temperatures file. Here is a [JSFiddle quickstart](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/be0qxyhs/).

Comment: This [Codepen](http://codepen.io/matt-west/pen/KjEHg) might also help you.

Comment: What is the question? I am a little confused on what are you looking for in an answer.